# Service Stack 4: return JSON with property that has rendered view

Tags: json, servicestack, partial-views, servicestack-razor

I am running ServiceStack 4.0.21.

Is it possible to render a partial view, but return that as a string property in JSON response?
If so, is there a method I can call from the ServiceStack.Razor library to accomplish this?

```
public object Get(Request request) {
    var html = RenderPartial(request);

    return new Response() {
        Name: "name",
        Id: "Id",
        Html: html
    };

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to pass a model into a method, and get back an html string?

Comment: what about http://razor.servicestack.net/ ?

Comment: Yes, I am using ServiceStack.Razor to return a PartialView, but I am trying to see if I can return the PartialView as a string property in a JSON response.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same.